# Where can I store a JSON document so that it can be accessed from a template helper multiple times?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In my code, I am trying to access a collection that stores information about books. I'm looping over an array that only stores the ID of each book. Then I am using that ID to query the book from a collection called Books, which stores complete information for each book

```
Template.myBorrows.helpers({
  storeInSession:function(ilendbooksId) {
    console.log("storeInSession is called");
    var currentBorrowBook = Books.findOne({_id: ilendbooksId});
    Session.setAuth('currentBorrowBook' , currentBorrowBook);
  },

  getAuthor: function() {
    var currentBorrowBook = Session.get('currentBorrowBook');
    return currentBorrowBook.ItemAttributes[0].Author[0];
  },
});
```

I am querying the book document by the book's _id in the Books collection. Then I am storing it in a session, then calling appropriate methods to get information. The only problem is that I have to do this for an array of books, so every time the previous document in the Session gets overwritten and all my data on my page changes to the most current Session document. How and where can I store each book's document and ensure that the correct information is displayed without it updating to the most current Session doc?

Comment: You're making your life unnecessarily complicated. Have you done any of the blaze-based tutorials for Meteor? You shouldn't set session variables in a helper - do it in an event handler instead. If you're looping over a collection of books you should not require a method call for each one and you can also access each book's properties directly in your template without even needing a helper.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. If I was looping over a collection that stored enough information about each book, yes I could just access each property. Im actually looping over an array that only stores the ID of each book. Then I am using that ID to query the book from a collection called Books, which stores complete information for each book.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment then, you have an array of document `_id`s and you want to fetch the document in your templates.

html:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
{{#each array}}
  {{#with doc}}
    Author: {{author}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  array(){ return theArrayOfIdsThatYouveDefined; },
  doc(){ return Books.findOne(this); }
});
```

Inside the `{{#each array}}` loop `this` will be an element of the array. The `doc` helper simply looks up a book from the `Books` collection and returns it. Now inside the `{{#with doc}}` block the data context will be a book object.

No session variables or method calls required.